Prevent Figure break the sentence
I have this problem. I have some text and an image. I'd like the sentence "Recent developments" not to continue two pages later. How should I resolve? Thanks
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/CF.png}    \caption{Example of prediction of user's rating with a Collaborative Filtering. The system forecasts a user's rating for an item that they haven't yet rated, basing these predictions on the ratings provided by other users who have shown similar preferences to the active user. For example, in this particular scenario, the system has predicted that the active user is likely to not favor the video, drawing on the rating patterns of users with comparable tastes.}
    \label{fig:CFExample}
\end{figure}



tex has no information about the sentence structure, just move the figure environment later in the source so it is placed later.

or quite possibly you could force that final 1-line end of paragraph on to the previous page so that it comes before the figure, but without any code shown impossible to say

Or  ... shorten the figure description by at least one line (which may be by just 1 word or so).

@MS-SPO currently it's a float page so even if thecaption was shorter the body text wouldn't go on that page
